# self.navigationController is null

Tags: iphone, navigationcontroller

in my viewcontroller,I have a button,when press the button,entry the navigationController,my code like:

```
-(IBAction)ShangHaiButtonPressed:(id)sender{
    marketviewcontroller = [[MarketViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MarketViewController" bundle:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",self.navigationController);
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:marketviewcontroller animated:YES];
    [marketviewcontroller release];   
}
```

but I can see the self.navigationController is null,how to solve this problem?thank you.

update:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    _switchviewcontroller = [[SwitchViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SwitchViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.window addSubview:_switchviewcontroller.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I guess your currentViewController in not in navigation controller stack hierarchy . add currentViewController to navigationcontroller should solve yr problem

Comment: In App delegate has the window Object ,In AppDidFinishLaunching method First create object for yr firstcontroller then create NavigationControllerObject like - [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:yrcurrentcontroller]; [self.window addSubView:navigationController.view]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The *navigationController* property of a view controller will return a valid navigation controller object only if the view controller is in a navigation controller's navigation stack. A view controller can be added to a navigation stack in the following ways.

1. By making the view controller the rootViewController of a navigation controller using *initWithRootViewController:* method of *UINavigationController*
2. By pushing the view controller using *pushViewController:* method of *UINavigationController*.

Make sure your view controller is added to the navigation stack in any of the above ways.

---

**EDIT:** (After the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: code added to the question):

Change the *didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:* method to this,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    _switchviewcontroller = [[SwitchViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SwitchViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_switchviewcontroller];
    [self.window addSubview:navController.view];
    [navController release];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

**Swift 4 (version):**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    switchviewcontroller = SwitchViewController(nibName: "SwitchViewController", bundle: nil)
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: switchviewcontroller)
    window.addSubview(navController.view)
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

Comment: I just have the above code about dealing with navigationController,so what else code I need to write,thank you.

Comment: You have *window -> currentViewController* and now you want to push *marketviewcontroller*, (ie) *window -> currentViewController -> marketviewcontroller* right?

Comment: Alright. Edit your question and paste the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` code of app delegate there.

Comment: thank you very much,and I will have a try.if it works ,I will accept your answer,thank you again.

Comment: You saved my day. Checked out to find out, that I'm pushing with presentViewController:animated

Answer (score 3):

This code will yield the solution you're looking for:

```
-(IBAction)ShangHaiButtonPressed:(id)sender {
     UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self];
     [self.view removeFromSuperview];
     [appDelegate.window addSubview:nav.view];   // appDelegate is the delegate of your Application
     marketViewController = [[MarketViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MarketViewController" bundle:nil];
     [nav pushViewController:marketViewController animated:YES];
     [marketViewController release];    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In AppDelegate.m file make your first view RootView for Navigation :

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    myView *Obj=[[myView alloc]initWithNibName:@"myView" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:Obj];
    nav.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    [window addSubview:nav.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

In your myView.m file add below code to navigate to myNewView from myView :

```
-(void) registerMethod {
    myNewView *obj = [[myView alloc] initWithNibName:@"myNewView" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];

    [obj release];
}
```